# Saving an instance of tkinter GUI

Tags: python, json, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a GUI with an "Add entry box" button that adds an entry box when clicked. I also want to add a "Save for next session" button that, when clicked, will load the current entries when the user opens the GUI next time. The problem is that sometimes it will be 5 fields to enter, other times 305. How can I save the number of input fields and their values? I don't want to use the pickle library.

```
import customtkinter
import threading
import tkinter

class MyGui:


    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.entry_list = []

        self.entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self.app, placeholder_text="entry")
        self.entry_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.add_entry_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.app, text="Add entry",    command=self.add_entry)
        self.add_entry_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.save_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.app, text="Save for next session",    command=self.save_instance)
        self.save_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    def add_entry(self):
        self.entry_list.append(self.entry_1)
        self.entry_1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self.app, placeholder_text="entry")
        self.entry_1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    def save_instance(self):
        pass

app = customtkinter.CTk()
running = MyGui(app)
app.mainloop()
```

As you can see I have this self.entry_list with all entry field objects, but I do not know how to use it to load the GUI instance later.

Comment: First, you can't pickle tkinter objects. Second, why not just store the input in a file? Entry's normally doesn't contain more text as a single line. So each line of text in your file is an entry. Try it for yourself and ask a specific question if you got problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some sort of storage mechanism. You don't want to use pickle, which is one mechanism. You can also use a flat file or a database. In this case, since you're using entry widgets, a flat file with the content of each entry is sufficient. A sqlite database might arguably be better, but in this specific case it might be overkill.

Whatever you choose, it's important to know that you can't save tkinter objects to disk. The implementation of tkinter makes that essentially impossible. So, you must save the data from which you can restore the tkinter object rather than saving the object itself.

In your case you're saving entries to the list `self.entry_list`, so writing the file could just be a matter of iterating over the entries to get the values and write them to a file (assuming you want to preserve the values)

The following example hard-codes the filename for brevity, but in production code you shouldn't hard-code it.

```
def save_instance(self):
    data = [entry.get() for entry in self.entry_list]
    with open("entries.txt", "w") as f:
        text = "\n".join(data)
        f.write(text)
```

Restoring the entries is just a matter of reversing the process. First, though, we need to modify `add_entry` to take the default value. Also, your implementation oddly uses `self.entry_1` which isn't necessary so I've removed it.

The following example assumes the data which was saved to the file is the default value of the entry widget. If instead, it's the name of the placeholder text you can easily make that modification.

```
def add_entry(self, text=""):
    entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self.app, placeholder_text="entry")
    self.entry_list.append(entry)
    entry.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
    entry.insert("end", text)
```

Next, create a method for reading the data and creating the entries. It's important to note that `readlines` includes the newline on each line, which we strip out.

```
def restore_entries(self):
    with open("entries.txt", "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        for line in data:
            self.add_entry(line.strip())
```

---

This definitely isn't the only way to solve the problem. If you don't want to save the default values (or placeholder text?) you could just store the number of entries you want to keep. Or, like I mentioned earlier, you could use a database. With a database you could store the number of rows, and then only save the text for the entries that have text. Or, instead of a flat file you could save the data in a structured format such as json.